# What the benefit of using taglib?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, xhtml, taglib

I am going to use Spring Web MVC Framework on Netbeans. Writing Web user interface do I really need to use taglib or can I aim the same functionality with XHTML? Is there any good reason for using taglib?
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a templating engine like [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) or [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/). If you wish to not go down a JSP route.  Although the Spring tags are pretty good as well.

Answer (score 2):

Taglibs simply equals code re-use that complies with the **Don't Repeat Yourself** principle.

Answer (score 2):

Use a taglib when you have view logic that would be too difficult or impossible to code using JSTL, and you don't want to use scriptlets (Java embedded in the page).   Unfortunately writing a taglib is fairly complex so in practice it's only done when really needed.

Oh yeah, and of course DRY :)